# jquery slider sliding extra block before cycling of images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a very basic slider using jQuery and I have been having a problem making it slide infinitely. I require the slider to slide back to 1st slide after it reaches the last slide.
I have almost achieved it but the problem is after reaching the last slide it is sliding an extra blank slide before sliding back to the 1st slide.

Please check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/basak_pratik/1r2xso45/6/).

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-container">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li>
  </ul>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="left">left</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="right">right</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  position: relative;
}

.slider-container ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.slider-container ul li {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #fc0;
}

#left {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

#right {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 100%;
}

.slider-container ul li:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color: #0cf;
}
```

JS:

```
var imgList = $('.slider-container ul li').length;
var imageListWidth = $('.slider-container ul li').width();
var totalWidth = imgList * imageListWidth;
$('.slider-container ul').width(totalWidth);
var shift = 0;

$('#left').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.slider-container ul').animate({
    marginLeft: shift - imageListWidth
  });
  shift = shift - imageListWidth;
  if (parseInt($('.slider-container ul').css('margin-left')) == (imageListWidth - totalWidth)) {
    console.log('inside if left');
    $('.slider-container ul').animate({
      marginLeft: 0
    });
    shift = 0;
  }
  console.log('margin value: ' + parseInt($('.slider-container ul').css('margin-left')));
});

$('#right').on('click', function() {
  $('.slider-container ul').animate({
    marginLeft: shift + imageListWidth
  });
  shift = shift + imageListWidth;
  if ($('.slider-container ul').css('margin-left') == '0px') {
    console.log('inside if right');
    $('.slider-container ul').animate({
      marginLeft: imageListWidth - totalWidth
    });
    shift = imageListWidth - totalWidth;
  }
});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would suggest using a Jquery plugin such as [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying problem is that you are animating the images right at the beginning of the click, regardless of whether or not you or on the last or first slide:

```
//no check being performed to see if this this animation is necessary
$('.slider-container ul').animate({
    marginLeft: shift + imageListWidth
});
```

What you should be doing is placing a check to see the current Index of the image being viewed, and then only choose to perform that initial animation of the current image index is not 0 or imglist. Example:

```
if (currentImageIndex != imgList) {
    $('.slider-container ul').animate({
        marginLeft: shift + imageListWidth
    });
}
```

If you did it this way you would of course need to create a currentImgIndex variable and monitor it as they click the slider.

Or of course you could base this check on the margin-left position of the whole ul, it is up to you what you base the check on, but you need to perform some kind of check before deciding to perform that initial animation.

This is just a quick re-do of your js code, i created this by editing your fiddle and it works:

```
var imgList = $('.slider-container ul li').length;
var imageListWidth = $('.slider-container ul li').width();
var totalWidth = imgList * imageListWidth;
$('.slider-container ul').width(totalWidth);
var shift = 0;
//Track which image is currently viewed
var imgIndex = 1;

$('#left').on('click', function(e) {
  if (imgIndex != imgList) {
    $('.slider-container ul').animate({
      marginLeft: shift - imageListWidth
    });
  }
  shift = shift - imageListWidth;
  if (parseInt($('.slider-container ul').css('margin-left')) == (imageListWidth - totalWidth)) {
    console.log('inside if left');
    $('.slider-container ul').animate({
      marginLeft: 0
    });
    shift = 0;
    e.dequeue();
  }

  imgIndex = (imgIndex + 1 <= imgList) ? imgIndex + 1: 1;
});

$('#right').on('click', function() {
  if (imgIndex != 1) {
    $('.slider-container ul').animate({
      marginLeft: shift + imageListWidth
    });
  }
  shift = shift + imageListWidth;
  if ($('.slider-container ul').css('margin-left') == '0px') {
    console.log('inside if right');
    $('.slider-container ul').animate({
      marginLeft: imageListWidth - totalWidth
    });
    shift = imageListWidth - totalWidth;
  }

  imgIndex = (imgIndex - 1 >= 1) ? imgIndex - 1: imgList;
});
```

Of course the code above could be more a bit more efficient etc., but I just did a quick mock-up for illustration purposes.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have to go for a checking before animating the slide. Thank you for the suggestion.

Note: The modification is working for 1st time but behaving inconsistently afterwards. Sorry but can't click the green code. :)

Comment: I get an error but only when clicking on the left button (not the right) - but the particular error I get only relates to the `e.dequeue()` line (which I'm not entirely sure is necessary). When I removed that code it worked fine for me

Comment: Yes.. missed out on checking the console for any kind of error. Sorry about that.